# Good method/approach in improving advanced Drupal development skills

Tags: 7, theming, community-official-site

This might be a bad place to post this, but here it goes.

I'm looking for a good approach in bettering my knowledge/skills to Drupal. I have been using it since D5 and I still feel like I am so 'unskilled' in doing advanced development. I still struggle with how to create a custom module or hook alter methods properly (with 1 try and not 10) through the template.php file. I have seen others create some insane modules or scripts and I just boggles me on how they come up with it.

It's always been trial-and-error for me, and sometimes I get it to work but never can get an answer on 'Why that worked'.

I have been a php developer for over 10+ years, touched a bit of C#, Ruby, and Java but nothing hugely professional. I have always been driven to continue pursuing Drupal development. Just so incredibly overwhelming still at times. I have high hopes to make the next DrupalCon in Austin, Texas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the [Drupal Examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples) module to be a great starting point for learning enough to develop my own modules, or to aid in solving a particularly thorny problem I'm having.

There's also the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and [Dev Themer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules, which help to illuminate some of what's going on behind the scenes.

Then there is the API documentation, which I personally have a harder time understanding until I read some of the comments.

These are the ones I use most; others will probably chime in with others, which I know about but lack enough experience in to form a helpful opinion.

Comment: Never heard of Drupal Examples. I tend to learn best by reverse engineering something. So that is perfect. Thanks for the heads up! 

Devel is great when theming node/field/field-collection tpl. But still so confusing on how to theme a form. 

I am not one to purchasing books (online tutorials usually are great alone) but have been tempted to buy a few Drupal dev books. Tons out there though, unsure which might be the best to start with for wanting to do advanced developed.

Comment: Have a look at D7 Module development and others from Packt books collection. Were great for me. Maybe not as advanced as you need

Comment: @Drupac Starting to figure out a few things that I just never understood using Drupal Examples and reverse engineering them. :)